# Add stuff to context in a django.views.generic.edit.CreateView

Tags: django, view

I'm using a CBGV `CreateView` in a Django project.

I need to add some stuff to the context variable only if the form is invalid.
Is it possible to do that in the `form_invalid()` somehow?

I know of the `get_context_data()` method but I don't know how to check if the form is invalid in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (populated) form is one of the elements passed in the kwargs to `get_context_data`. You can get it from there and call `is_valid()` on it.